# How would I be able to return which instance belongs to the random number in my list. Without using a million if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

what I am trying to do, is `return`the instance, which range has the value from a `random.randint()` in a list.... Example...

```
class Testing:

    def __init__(self, name, value):

        self.name = name
        self.value = value

randomtest = Testing('First', range(1, 50))
randomtest_2 = Testing('Second', range(50, 100))

selections = []
counter = 0

while counter < 2:
    counter =+ 1

    selector = random.randint(1, 100)
    selections.append(selector)
```

But I don't want to use a million if statements to determine which index in the selections list it belongs to.. Like this:

```
if selections[0] in list(randomtest.value):
    return True

elif selections[0] in list(randomtest_2.value):
    return True
```

Your help is much appreciated, I am fairly new to programming and my head has just come to a stand still at the moment.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but can't use simply use a `for` loop? `for x in selections: if x in randomtest: return x` or whatevery exactly you want? If not, can you provide example input and output? Or maybe someone else understands you better.

Comment: So basically if I have 10 Testing instances all whith a different value = to a `.range()` I would call an RNG 10 times... And append each random int to a list.

I then need to check every index in that list against every Testing instance's value to see which ones the RNG picked.

Comment: Make a list of your test objects and loop through them like you normally would and return the appropriate one(s). `if selections[0] in list(tests[i].value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a set for your `selections` object then check the intersection with `set.intersection()` method:

ex:

```
In [84]: a = {1, 2}

In [85]: a.intersection(range(4))
Out[85]: {1, 2}
```

and in your code:

```
if selections.intersection(randomtest.value):
    return True
```

You can also define a `hase_intersect` method for your `Testing` class, in order to cehck if an iterable object has intersection with your obejct:

```
class Testing:

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def hase_intersect(self, iterable):
        iterable = set(iterable)
        return any(i in iterable for i in self.value)
```

And check like this:

```
if randomtest.hase_intersect(selections):
    return True
```

based on your comment, if you want to check the intersection of a spesific list against a set of objects you have to iterate over the 
set of objects and check the intersection using aforementioned methods. But if you want to refuse iterating over the list of objects you should probably use a base claas
with an special method that returns your desire output but still you need to use an iteration to fild the name of all intended instances. Thus, if you certainly want to
create different objects you neend to at least use 1 iteration for this task.